# Conversion from VBA to Javascript

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am trying to convert some VBA excel code to JS, but even I was sure of me, the code does not work properly.
Here are the snippets which cause me problems :

```
VBA: Tri1 = Tri1 + 2 ^ (2 - Tour)
JS: tri1 = tri1 + Math.pow(2, (2 - tour));
```

And:

```
VBA: If (y And (2 ^ (5 - Tour))) <> (Tri2 And 2 ^ (5 - Tour)) Then
JS: if ((y && Math.pow(2, 5 - tour)) != (tri2 && Math.pow(2, 5 - tour)))
```

And :

```
VBA: If (Tri1 And 2 ^ (2 - Tour)) = 0 Then
JS: if ((tri1 && Math.pow(2, 2 - tour)) == 0)
```

tri1, tri2 and y are all integers.

I have good understanding of JS, but none in VBA. So I googled a lot before already.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working? What are the inputs, what you expect, what you actually get?

Comment: I expect the same results that the VBA ones... I can't clarify much, cause I don't know the outputs in VBA line by line. The inputs are for example : y = 0 to 7; tour = 1; tri1 = 0 (first iteration); tri = 0 (first iteration); But is my "translation" is correct ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but I think that information could get you to the goal. Because you are just trying to translate the words from vba to js. But js is not vba and js has some special things.

**First: Floating numbers**

A floating number in js is not always that like it looks like. That question here will give you more information about that topic:
[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Because of the code snipets I don't know if one of your variables is a floating number. But if, you should know about that problem.

**Second: Comparison**

The way JS is handling comparisons is a litle bit different to some other languages. Some helpful links about that topic:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
- [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-JavaScript-comparisons)

Specially the comparisons in your code are not very clear. For example:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 0;
document.write((a && b) == 0); // is true
document.write(a && b) // is 0
var a = 10;
var b = 11;
document.write((a && b) == 0); // is false
document.write(a && b) // is 11
```

Is that really the behaviour you want to have? So try to simplify your comparisons and your code could work.

Comment: After struggling with this a few hours, I found my mistake : "And" in VBA, in these case is "&" in JS, the binary operator... Thanks anyway